# What is a succinct rank data structure? How does it work?

Tags: data-structures, bit, rank, space-complexity

I've heard of a class of data structures called ***succinct rank data structures***. What do these data structures do? What does "succinct" mean here? And how do they work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ***binary ranking problem*** is the following. You're given an array of bits, which we'll denote B. The bit array B has n bits in it. The goal is to preprocess B so that you can efficiently answer queries of the following form:

> Given an index i, what is the sum of the first i bits of the array?

This is called a ***rank query***, and we'll denote it as rank(i).

For example, suppose you were given this bit array:

```
11011100101110111100
```

With our notation from above, rank(5) would be the sum of the first five bits of the array. Those bits are `11011`, so we'd have that rank(5) = 4. Similarly, you can check that rank(10) = 6. As an edge case, we have rank(0) = 0, since if you add up no bits you get back 0.

Intuitively, this seems like a pretty easy problem to solve. We can preprocess the array by simply writing down all the prefix sums in a separate array. That might look like this:

[image: The bit array 11011100101110111100 annotated with the prefix sums at each point. Those prefix sums are 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 13, 13.]

With things set up this way, we can, in time O(1), compute rank(i) by simply looking up index i in this auxiliary array.

So... we're done, right? Unfortunately, no. Let's take a minute to think about how much total space this array takes up. It's an array of n+1 integers (we have one array element for each position in the array, plus one more right after the last element of the array), and so it sure seems like this would use O(n) total space. While in a sense this is true, though, this figure is misleading.

Imagine, for example, that we're on a 64-bit machine, where each integer is represented as a group of 64 bits. A naive implementation of the above approach might use 64 bits for each of the integers in our array, meaning that we'll need to use (roughly) 64n total bits for this array. Compare this against the amount of space required to write out our original array of bits B. The array B is n bits long, so it uses only n bits of memory. This means that our auxiliary table, which stores all the prefix sums, uses ***64 times*** as much space as the original bit array itself!

We might shrug this off as not that big a problem. Sure, it's 64× bigger than the original array - but is that a problem? And unfortunately, it is indeed an issue. Many of the applications where you would want a bit array like this, such as storing massive text strings or gigantic trees, work with data sets that just barely fit into memory to begin with. Figure, for example, that you're working with an array of bits that's 1GB long. In that case, storing this auxiliary array would take up 64 × 1GB = 64GB of memory to write out - an enormous amount of memory! At least in 2022 when I'm writing this, that's way more than your average desktop machine has. (If you're reading this in the 2030s, just change "GB" to "TB" and you'll have the same visceral reaction that us 2020ers feel. ^_^)

Our goal in this discussion will be to build a data structure that allows us to quickly answer rank queries, but which uses as few extra bits of memory as possible. This will take us into some unusual territory. We'll be quantifying the space usage of our data structures by counting up the total number of bits we use, which means that we *cannot* say that storing a single integer uses O(1) memory. And we'll need to bust out some clever techniques that, while well known to the community of data structures researchers, aren't that common in general computer science or software engineering.

### Step 1: Use Space-Efficient Numbers

Our first step in this journey will be to take the above idea - make an array of integers that stores all the possible prefix sums - and to whittle down the 64× memory blowup to something more reasonable.

To see how to do this, let's imagine that we're working with an array of bits that's exactly 1023 bits long. Why 1023 bits? It's because that's exactly 2<sup>10</sup> - 1 bits. Now, suppose we were to write down prefix sums for each of the bits in that array. Because our array of bits only has 2<sup>10</sup> - 1 bits in it, each prefix sum will be a number between between 0 and 2<sup>10</sup> - 1, inclusive. (Why? Because each bit is either 0 or 1, and in the absolute worst case when all bits are 1, the total sum will be 2<sup>10</sup> - 1.) If you think back to how binary numbers are represented, this means that each of our prefix sums can be represented as a 10-bit number. It would be wasteful to use a full 64-bit integer to write out each of these prefix sums; we'd only be using 10 of those 64 bits, and the other 54 bits would always be zeros!

If we were to look at how this would be represented in memory, it would look something like this:

[image: A schematic of a 1,023-bit array with a separate array running down the side made of prefix sums of those bits. Each prefix sum is written out as a 10-bit number.]

Most programming languages (and chips, for that matter) don't support working with an array of 10-bit integers. But thanks to the power of bitwise operations, we can easily simulate something like this. We'll form an array whose elements are 64-bit integers. We'll then completely ignore the fact that they're 64-bit integers and instead just treat our array as a long stream of bits. To get a particular 10-bit integer value out of that array, we just need to do some bitwise operators to locate which 64-bit integer(s) hold our 10-bit value, then extract the relevant bits and reassemble them. It's not the most straightforward calculation to do, but it's also not that terrible. Here's some C code for this:

```
/* Given an array of elements that are each bit_width bits long,
 * represented as an array of 64-bit integers holding the relevant
 * bits, extract the element at position index. It's assumed that
 * bit_width <= 64.
 *
 * "Beware of bugs in [this] code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it."
 */
uint64_t extract_bits_from(uint64_t* bit_array,
                           unsigned bit_width,
                           unsigned index) {
    assert(0 < bit_width && bit_width <= 64);

    /* Special-case the scenario where we want a 64-bit value,
     * which just means we do an array read.
     */
    if (bit_width == 64) return bit_array[index];

    /* Otherwise, we have 63 or fewer bits. */

    /* Logical index of the first bit that we want to extract. */
    unsigned first_bit = bit_width * index;

    /* Physical index into the array of 64-bit integers where we
     * need to look.
     */
    unsigned int_index = first_bit / 64;
    uint64_t first_int = bit_array[int_index];

    /* Determine how many bits we're going to pull from this
     * number. To do this, we'll look at the offset of the bit
     * position we start at and see where that falls in our 64-
     * bit value.
     */
    unsigned bit_start = first_bit % 64;

    /* There are two options. The first is that all the bits we
     * need are in this integer. In that case, extract them and
     * go home.
     */
    if (bit_start + bit_width <= 64) {
        /* Shift everything down by the appropriate amount,
         * then mask off the higher bits.
         */
        return (first_int >> bit_start) & ((1ULL << bit_width) - 1);
    }

    /* Otherwise, pull the lower bits from this integer and the
     * higher bits from the next integer. First, we have to see
     * how many bits to read.
     */
    unsigned low_bit_count = 64 - bit_start;
    uint64_t low_bits = (first_int >> bit_start) & ((1ULL << low_bit_count) - 1);

    unsigned high_bit_count = bit_start - 64;
    uint64_t next_int = bit_array[int_index + 1];
    uint64_t high_bits = next_int & ((1ULL << high_bit_count) - 1);

    return low_bits | (high_bits << low_bit_count);
}
```

In the specific case where we're working with an array of 2<sup>10</sup> - 1 bits, this approach will require an auxiliary array of 10n bits. That's *much* lower than the 64n bits we started with, though it's still a huge blowup over the original array size.

Before moving on, let's take a minute to generalize this idea. If our array has 2<sup>10</sup> - 1 bits in it, we need 10 bits per number. Similar reasoning tells us that if our array has 2<sup>15</sup> - 1 bits, we need 15 bits per number. Running this process backwards, you can work out that with an array of n bits, we need log<sub>2</sub> (n+1) bits to write out each prefix sum. This means that, in the general case, this approach will allow us to answer rank queries in time O(1), and will use **O(n log n)** total bits.

We can then ask: is there a way to knock down our space usage? Fortunately, the answer is yes. But to get there, we're going to need to make a series of clever insights.

### Step 2: Write Down Fewer Numbers

Why is our space usage O(n log n) right now? That's because

- we are writing down an array of O(n) numbers, and
- each number requires O(log n) bits.

To reduce our space usage, we either need to write down fewer total numbers, or write down fewer bits per number, or, ideally, both. Right now it might not be clear how to do either of these, but it turns out that each of these ideas becomes pretty natural once we look at things the right way.

Our first step will be to use this first idea and to write down fewer numbers. Here's a nice way of thinking about how to do this. Right now, we're writing down a prefix sum right before each of the numbers, as shown here:

[image: A bit array, alongside a secondary array that stores the prefix sums at each number]

That makes it easy to answer rank queries: we can just look in our array of prefix sums and read off the answer.

However, here's a cute little observation. Suppose that instead of storing the prefix sums just before each bit, we store the prefix sum before every *other* bit. That would look like this:

[image: The same diagram as above, except that every other entry of the prefix array has been removed.]

This might seem like a strange idea - we've just thrown away half the prefix sums! - and yet it still lets us query prefix sums efficiently (in time O(1)). Here's how. If you want to compute a prefix sum at an *even*-numbered position, just read off the precomputed value within that array slot. For example, to compute rank(6), we'd look up the array entry at index 6 / 2 = 3, zero-indexed. That's 5, which is indeed the correct answer.

If you want to compute a prefix sum at an *odd*-numbered position, on the other hand, we won't be able to read off a precomputed value right from the get-go. However, our odd-numbered entry is right next to an even-numbered entry. We can compute the prefix sum by reading the even-numbered entry right before us, then adding in the value of the bit that appears right after that position. For example, to compute rank(5), we'd first compute rank(4) = 3 by looking at our precomputed array. Then, we'd look at the bit at index 5 (zero-indexed) in the bit array. It's a 1, so the answer to our rank query is 3 + 1 = 4. Tada!

Overall, this approach halves the amount of extra memory we're using (we've thrown away half of our numbers), and our queries are just about as fast as before. Whereas previously we had just had to look up a single array entry, now we have to look up an array entry, then look at one bit from the original array of bits.

We've just cut our memory usage down by half - a huge improvement from before! Could we take this idea further? The answer is yes. We'll begin by picking some integer b that we'll call our ***block size***. We'll then group our array of bits apart into ***blocks*** of b bits each. Then, we'll only write down prefix sums at the start of each block, effectively only storing a 1/b fraction of the original number of prefix sums we started with. For example, here's what this might look like on a sample bitvector with b=8:

[image: A bitvector of 48 bits. It's been subdivided into 6 blocks of 8 bits each. At the start of each block, we've written the sum of all the bits before that block]

To see how to compute rank queries here, let's work through rank(30), the sum of the first 30 bits. The idea here is a generalization of what we did earlier: we'll find the last array entry where we have a prefix sum computed, then add in the missing bits from the array itself. Here's how we do this.

1. First, we compute ⌊30/8⌋ = 3, the index of the block where the query ends. We then look at array entry 3 (zero-indexed) to get the sum of all the bits up to the start of that block, which is 14.
2. The number we have is the sum of the first 24 bits, and we want the sum of the first 30. To do this, we need to read 30 % 8 = 6 more bits from the block. So read the first six bits of block 3 (zero-indexed) and add them up. Doing this, we find that the sum of those bits is 4.
3. Add these numbers together to get 14 + 4 = 18, our final answer.

How fast is this approach? Well, step (1) always takes time O(1). It's just an array lookup. Step (2), however, depends on how big we make our blocks. If b is small, we won't have to scan over too many bits. If b is large, we'll have to scan a large number of bits. Overall, the total work we do ends up being O(b).

But what of our space usage? Well, if we were to store the full array of prefix sums, we'd use O(n log n) space: there would be (roughly) n numbers, each of which uses (roughly) log<sub>2</sub> n bits. But now that we're only storing the prefix sums at the start of each block, we're storing only roughly 1/b of these prefix sums. That means we now are storing approximately n / b prefix sums, each of which still needs approximately log<sub>2</sub> n bits. That makes our space usage O((n log n) / b).

So we're now left with an interesting situation:

- Our space usage is O((n log n) / b) bits. This means we want to make b large so that we don't use too much memory.
- Our query time is O(b). This means that we want to keep b small so that our rank queries can be done quickly.

There is no optimal choice of b to make here to balance out these forces. If you absolutely must get rank queries running quickly, you'd have to pick a small choice of b and pay some extra memory cost. On the other hand, if you're okay with slower queries, you could crank b up pretty high to drop the space usage down to a manageable amount.

This leads to a question: is there a way to get the best of both worlds? That is, can we get lower space usage while also getting fast queries? The answer, surprisingly, is yes! Let's see how we get there.

### Step Three: Write Down Smaller Numbers

Earlier on, we mentioned that there were two different ways we could try to reduce our O(n log n) storage space. The first was to *store fewer numbers*. We've done that by only writing down prefix sums every so often. The second was to *write down fewer bits per number*. That might seem impossible, but when you look at it the right way it's actually not too bad. Let's explore that second option.

As a refresher of where we are right now, we've broken our array apart into blocks of b bits each, for some parameter b we can choose however we'd like. We've then written down the prefix sums at the start of each block. Things look like this:

[image: A schematic of breaking bits apart into blocks of b bits each, then writing the prefix sum at the start of each block]

Currently, the cost of performing a rank query is O(b). That's because as part of a rank query, we have to scan across the bits of a block, adding them up, and the way we're doing that is by running a linear scan across those bits. Is there a way to speed things up?

Indeed there is, and this is where we get to an important insight. If you think about it, scanning across the bits of a block and adding them up is essentially the same as ***performing a rank query on a smaller array of bits***. That is, we've started off by trying to answer the question "what is the sum of the first i bits *of the overall array?*," and we've turned it into "what is the sum of the first i % b bits *of the block we end up in?*" In other words, we're left with a smaller version of the same problem we started off with!

What can we do with this information? Our very first strategy for performing rank queries was to write down prefix sums for each bit. That would allow us to very quickly compute prefix sums without having to read over lots of bits from the original number. Let's try repeating this idea here. What happens if, within each block, we write down the prefix sums before each bit? That might look like this:

[image: The two-level structure. At the top level, we subdivide our bitvector into blocks of size b, and write down the prefix sums at the start of each block. Within each block, we write down prefix sums for the bits in that block. For example, for the block 11000100, we'd write down the numbers 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]

Here, I've shown the prefix sums within just one of these blocks, but we'd have similar prefix sums running across all the blocks. I just couldn't find a way to fit that all into one picture. :-)

Here's what a query now looks like. Suppose we want to compute rank(20), the sum of the first 20 bits. Here's how we do it.

- As before, we compute ⌊20 / 8⌋ = 2 to get the index of the block where the query ends. We then read index 2 (zero-indexed) from the top-level array of prefix sums to get the sum of the bits up to the start of this block, which is 11.
- Now, we look within our block. We currently know the sum of the first 16 bits, and so we need to get the sum of the first 20 % 8 = 4 bits of this block. To do that, we look at the table for this block and read entry 4 (zero-indexed). Doing so tells us that the sum of the first four bits of the block is 2.
- We add these values together, which gives us our total of 11 + 2 = 13, which is the correct answer.

Notice that this entire process is driven by table lookups - there are no linear scans required! And in fact, regardless of what choice we make for our block size b, we end up doing O(1) work per query: the cost of doing the necessary divisions, mods, and table reads. Amazing!

How much space does this approach need? There are two components to this. The first place where we're using auxiliary storage space is for that top-level array of prefix sums. As we saw before, if we have blocks of b bits each, this uses O((n log n) / b) bits.

But now we have to factor in the space required to write down prefix sums within each of the blocks. How much space will we need for this? The major insight we need here is that ***prefix sums within a block use fewer bits than prefix sums across the whole array***. In an array of n bits, each prefix sum requires O(log n) bits, since the prefix sum can be anything from 0 to n, inclusive. But in a block of b bits, where b is probably *much* smaller than n, we only need to use **O(log b)** bits for a prefix sum, since within a block the sum can range from 0 to b, inclusive. This will turn out to be a major idea for us in designing these data structures: if you have a smaller array, you need fewer bits for your prefix sums!

To work out how much total space is needed for all those prefix sums across the whole data structure, we can use the following calculation. In each block of b bits, we will write down b prefix sums, each of which is O(log b) bits long, so we need O(b log b) total bits. And since there are roughly n / b blocks (n bits are grouped into blocks of b bits each), the total space usage for the relative indices within each block is **O(n log b)**.

Overall, this means that the total amount of memory we're using for this two-level approach is **O((n log n) / b + n log b)** bits. That's a weird expression, so let's take a minute to unpack it.

- If we pick b to be tiny, then our blocks have few bits each. This means that the O(n log b) term is small. However, this also means that we have a large number of blocks, so our O((n log n) / b) term will be too big.
- If we pick b to be huge, then we won't have that many blocks. Specifically, we'll have n / b blocks, and for huge values of b this quantity is small. That means that the O((n log n) / b) term will be small. However, with a large value of b, our blocks get huge, and the number of bits required to write down an offset within a block will get too big (i.e. the O(n log b) term will be too big).

The fact that making b too small or too big isn't good for our overall space usage suggests that there's an optimal choice of b to make that would balance these terms out. And indeed there is! If we pick **b = O(log n)** (that is, pick b to be some multiple of log n), then our overall space usage is minimized. In particular, our space usage comes back as follows:

> O((n log n) / b + n log b)
>
> = O((n log n) / log n + n log log n)
>
> = O(n + n log log n)
>
> = **O(n log log n)**

Et voila! We've gotten our space usage down to **O(n log log n)** bits. Keep in mind that for any reasonable value of n, the quantity log log n is *tiny*. For example, suppose you have an array of n = 2<sup>64</sup> bits. Then log n = 64 (assuming we're using base-2 logarithms, which we are) and log log n = 6. This is a great improvement on our original O(n log n) bits of storage space!

And yet, while log log n is a small number, because our solution uses O(n log log n) bits of memory, it still requires more memory than the original array of bits we started with. Is there a way to drop the space usage even further?

Of course, the answer is yes. And doing so will involve some surprising mathematics.

(This is Part One of a two-part answer. [Part Two is available here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72580833/501557))

Answer (score 7):

(This is Part Two of a two-part answer. [Part one is available here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72580831/501557))

### Step 4: Think Recursively

Let's take a minute to think about how we got here. We started off by computing the prefix sum at each bit, as shown here:

[image: Our original idea]

This used O(n log n) total bits.

Then we saw that we could reduce the number of bits by subdividing our array into blocks of size log n, only computing the prefix sums at the start of those blocks, and then within each block writing out local prefix sums, as shown here:

[image: Our second approach]

This used O(n log log n) bits, a major improvement from before. What we learned here is the following insight: ***if you're going to write out prefix sums, it's better to subdivide into blocks before doing so.***

And with that insight in mind, let's look back at where we are right now. Within our new structure, we are still writing out prefix sums within each block. But we also know that if you're going to write out prefix sums, it's better to subdivide into smaller pieces. Could we apply this idea within each block? Here's the idea. We'll subdivide each block into "miniblocks" of some size we'll pick later. Within each block, we'll write out our prefix sums at the start of each miniblock, and then, within the miniblock write out prefix sums for each of the miniblock elements. That might look like this:

[image: Our three-level structure. We subdivide the array of bits into blocks, and subdivide each block into miniblocks. We write down prefix sums at the start of each block, at the start of each miniblock, and within the bits of each miniblock.]

As before, for space reasons I haven't drawn out the subdivision of each block into miniblocks, nor the prefix sums within each miniblock, since doing so would result in a diagram that doesn't fit on the screen. :-)

The procedure for doing a rank query here is essentially the same as what we did with the two-level structure, just now with three levels. We figure out which block our query ends in, then write down the prefix sum at the start of the block. Then we find our which miniblock our query ends in, and write down the prefix sum at the start of the miniblock. Finally, we look up the prefix sum within the miniblock using the table we precomputed at the very bottom level. All of these steps take time O(1), so queries still take time O(1).

What does this do to our space usage? Intuitively, based on what we saw before, this should use less memory than our initial approach. But we have to work out the math to check whether that is indeed the case. Let's do that here.

At the top level, we've subdivided our array into blocks of size log n. There are, therefore, roughly n / log n blocks. A prefix sum at the top level ranges from 0 to n, inclusive, so each prefix sum uses O(log n) bits. Overall, that uses O((n / log n) log n) = O(n) bits.

At the second level, we've subdivided our blocks into "miniblocks." Let's say that our miniblocks have size b'. There are a total of O(n / b') miniblocks. At the start of each miniblock, we write down the prefix sum within the block. Those prefix sums range from 0 to log n bits, inclusive, since our block size is log n. This means that we need O(log log n) bits per prefix sum here. Overall, for this second level, we therefore need O((n log log n) / b') bits.

Now let's look at the third level. At each of the n bits in our original bit array, we'll need to write down the prefix sum at that bit within its miniblock. If each miniblock has size b', then the maximum prefix sum within a miniblock is b', so we need O(log b') bits for each of these numbers. This collectively takes O(n log b') bits.

When we add all these terms together, we're left with a space usage of O((n log log n) / b' + n log b') bits. As before, picking b' to be too small will mean our miniblocks aren't big enough and we'll use too much space within each block writing down prefix sums (the O((n log log n) / b') term will be too big). If we pick b' to be too big, then we'll use too many bits writing down offsets within a miniblock (the O(n log b') term will be too big). There's some optimal point at which we'd set b' to minimize the space usage, and it happens to be the case that this is when b' = O(log log n) (that is, b' is some constant multiple of log log n). When we choose b' this way, our space usage works out to **O(n log log log n)** bits - yet another improvement in the total amount of bits we use!

At this point, you might spot a pattern. If we don't split into blocks at all, we use O(n log n) bits. If we split into blocks of size log n, we use O(n log log n) bits. If we split into miniblocks of size log log n, we use O(n log log log n) bits. Can we keep this up?

We can, but we're going to need to introduce some new notation in order to see how. :-)

Let's define **log<sup>(k)</sup> n** to be the logarithm function applied k times to the number n. So, for example:

- log<sup>(0)</sup> n = n
- log<sup>(1)</sup> n = log n
- log<sup>(2)</sup> n = log log n
- log<sup>(3)</sup> n = log log log n
- ...

Let's now reframe our previous approaches.

- If we split into blocks 0 times, our space usage is O(n log<sup>(1)</sup> n).
- If we split into blocks 1 time, our space usage is O(n log<sup>(2)</sup> n).
- If we split into blocks 2 times, our space usage is O(n log<sup>(3)</sup> n).

More generally, if we subdivide into blocks, then subdivide those blocks into blocks again, then subdivide *those* blocks into blocks again, etc., each time making our blocks logarithmically smaller than what we started with, and do this k total times, it looks like our space usage is O(n log<sup>(k+1)</sup> n). Is that a coincidence?

Turns out, no, it's not a coincidence, but there are a few details we have to watch out for. We can consider the following recursive construction that builds a data structure for ranking.

- If n is "sufficiently small," (say, n ≤ 2), just write down prefix sums for each bit.
- Otherwise, split your array of n items apart into blocks of size b = log n. Write down prefix sums at the start of each block. Then, recursively apply this construction to each block.

If this recursion goes on for k layers, you can work out that the space usage works out to O(nk + n log<sup>(k)</sup> n). The query time, if this goes on for k layers, is O(k), since at each layer we have to find which block we belong to and send the recursion a bit deeper.

Just by eyeballing things, we can guess that k is going to be *tiny* compared to n. After all, every time we go through the recursion, the value of n shrinks by a log factor, and that's going to massively reduce how big it is! As an example, suppose we pick n to be [the number of protons known to exist in the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe), which is approximately 2<sup>256</sup>. Then

- At the top level of the recursion, n = log<sup>(0)</sup> 2<sup>256</sup> = 2<sup>256</sup>.
- At the level below this, n = log<sup>(1)</sup> 2<sup>256</sup> = 256.
- At the level below this, n = log<sup>(2)</sup> 2<sup>256</sup> = 8.
- At the level below this, n = log<sup>(3)</sup> 2<sup>256</sup> = 3.
- At the level below this, n = log<sup>(4)</sup> 2<sup>256</sup> ≈ 1.58.

In other words, once we're five layers deep in the recursion, we've reduced the size of our input from "how many protons are estimated to be in the universe" to something smaller than two. There really aren't going to be that many layers here!

To quantify this, we can introduce the [iterated logarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm), denoted **log* n**. The value of log* n is, intuitively, "how many times you have to take a logarithm before you drop the number to 2 or lower." So, for example, log* 2<sup>256</sup> = 5. This function grows *absurdly* slowly. In fact, to find a value of n where log* n ≥ 10, we need to look at the number

> 2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

which exceeds anything that anyone has ever conceived of that could fit into the known universe.

Putting all this together, we now know that the number of layers of recursion used here is log* n. That means that the space usage for our structure is now

> O(nk + n log<sup>(k)</sup> n)
>
> = **O(n log* n)**,

and our query time is now O(log* n). For all intents and purposes, this is linear space usage and constant query time, since, as mentioned above, the smallest n where log* n exceeds 10 requires crazily iterated exponents to represent. Amazing!

So... we're done, right? Well, unfortunately, no. Here's why. First, from a practical perspective, while our space usage is essentially "some small constant times n" (say, 4n or 5n bits), we're still left with a situation where our data structure requires more space to store than the original array of bits. And if n is large, we might not have enough space in memory to store 4n or 5n bits.

Second, speaking as a proud citizen of Theoryland, there is a gap - albeit a shockingly small gap, but a gap nonetheless - between O(n log* n) and O(n) and between O(log* n) and O(1). What we'd ultimately want to do is get something that truly does use O(n) space with query times of O(1).

At this point it might not be clear how to get there. We've already seen the two major ideas from before - writing out fewer numbers, and writing out smaller numbers - and carried them to their logical conclusion. And indeed, to the best of my knowledge these ideas on their own can't push the space usage down further. To make additional progress, we're going to need to incorporate a new technique, one that's commonly employed in the data structures research community, but one that is almost unheard of in the general CS community. That technique goes by a mysterious title: *the Method of Four Russians*.

### Step 5: Use the Method of Four Russians

To understand where we're going, I want to jump us backwards in time to the first place we ever tried subdividing our array of bits into blocks. That's when our data structure looked like this:

[image: Splitting the array into blocks and writing down the prefix sums at the start of each block]

At this point, we'd split our array into blocks of some size b and  written down the prefix sums at the start of each block. At the time we did this, we didn't know how big our blocks would be. Later on, we found out that choosing b = log n (or, more generally, choosing b to be some multiple of log n) worked out particularly well. Subjectively, log n is *substantially* smaller than n. In other words, intuitively, we're picking blocks that are absolutely tiny from the perspective of the size of our original input.

Let's play around with this idea a bit. For now, let's move away from the idea that we're picking blocks of size log n, and instead imagine that we pick a block size that's generally "very small." For example, suppose we pick our block size to be b = 3, and, as before, write down prefix sums at the start of each block. Here's what that might look like:

[image: An array broken apart into blocks of size 3. The blocks are 110, 111, 001, 011, 101, 111, 000, 100, 110, 101, 101, and 110.]

And now, for an observation that's going to get us a lot of mileage. I picked this particular bit array and block size because there are 12 total blocks. However, with b = 3, there are only 8 possible distinct blocks. Those are shown here:

```
000  001  010  011  100  101  110  111
```

By the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), since there are more total blocks in our subdivision than there are different combinations of three bits, some of these blocks must appear multiple times in the original array.

"Okay," you might be saying. "So some blocks get repeated. Why is that significant?" To see why, think about our two-layer structure. As a reminder of how our two-layer structure worked, we

- subdivided the original array into blocks of some size, writing down prefix sums at the start of each block, then
- wrote down prefix sums within each block.

Here's what that might look like with b = 3:

[image: The two-layer structure with b = 3. Specifically highlighted is the fact that the second-level arrays are the same for two separate copies of the block 101]

As before, I can't draw out the entire bottom layer because it won't fit on your screen. But I've drawn enough to point out a key detail. In this array are three copies of the block `101`. Importantly, ***the prefix sums within those blocks are identical***, since the blocks have the same bits. It doesn't matter where in the top-level array those blocks appear. The prefix sums within the block just care about the sums of the bits purely in the block, not the surrounding context.

If our goal is to reduce space usage, this seems like a prime opportunity. Each of those blocks needs to know what its prefix sums are, but there's no reason for us to write out separate copies of those prefix sums every time we see that block. We could imagine just writing down the prefix sums once per block, then finding some way to share those prefix sums across the blocks. If we could do that, assuming that we were guaranteed that the same blocks would repeat over and over again, we could potentially save a lot of space!

Here's what this might look like. We'll pick some block size b. There are 2<sup>b</sup> possible blocks of size b, since each bit can either be 0 or 1 and there are b total bits. For each of those 2<sup>b</sup> possible blocks, there are b+1 prefix sums we need to store, one for each bit and one for after all those bits. We could therefore form a table containing O(2<sup>b</sup> · b) entries representing every possible prefix sum query that could ever be made on any possible block. For b = 3, that would look like this:

[image: A precomputed table of all possible blocks and all queries within a block with b = 3.]

To see how to use this table, let's see how to query rank(17). Here's how this would work:

1. As with a regular two-level structure, we begin by determining what block our query ends in. To do that, we compute ⌊17 / 3⌋ = 5. We're therefore in block number 5 (zero-indexed), and we can read off the prefix sum up to the start of the block, which is 10.
2. We know the sum of the first 15 bits, but we need the sum of the first 17 bits. We therefore need to compute the sum of the first 17 % 5 = 2 bits within this block. To do so, we consult our table! Our block is `111`, and we want to look up the sum of the first two bits. Consulting our table, we see that the sum of the first two bits of this block is 2.
3. We add these two values together to get 10 + 2 = 12, which is the correct answer.

The key to making this run fast is the following: each block is a series of bits, ***which can be interpreted as a number***. For example, our block, `111`, is the number 7. We can therefore use the bits of the block themselves as an index into our table! The cost of this lookup is then the cost of a regular 2D table lookup, which is O(1). Amazing!

Now, how much space does this approach use? Some of you may have noticed that the number of possible blocks of size b is 2<sup>b</sup> and felt a twinge of suspicion. The function 2<sup>b</sup> grows *very* quickly as a function of b, which means that we'd need to pick very small blocks for this to work! And indeed we will - but hold that thought for now.

To work out the exact details of how much space we'll need, we need to account for two separate parts of the structure. First, there's the top-level array of running prefix sums up to the start of each block. As we've seen before, that will use O((n log n) / b) bits.

Next, and most importantly, is our table. As we saw earlier, this table will have dimensions 2<sup>b</sup> × (b + 1), since there are 2<sup>b</sup> possible blocks of size b and each block can be queried at b+1 indices. That means our table has O(2<sup>b</sup> · b) entries.

But, as we've seen many a time in the course of this journey, we then have to ask: how may bits is each entry? Each entry stores a number between 0 and b, inclusive, and therefore uses O(log b) bits. Putting this all together, we end up with a table that needs O(2<sup>b</sup> · b · log b) total bits. (Wow, it's like three exponential generations of b! You have the "grandparent" 2<sup>b</sup>, the "parent" b, and the "child" log b. ^_^)

Overall, this means that our space usage is O((n log n) / b + 2<sup>b</sup> · b · log b). Let's think about what this means.

- If b is too small, then, as with our previous structures based on breaking things apart into blocks, we will have too many blocks and therefore O((n log n) / b) will be too big. In particular, if we're gunning for O(n) total space, we need b to be approximately log n.
- If b is too large, then there will be way too many possible blocks of size b. In particular, if b is too large, the O(2<sup>b</sup> · b · log b) term will be too big. In particular, if we want our total space usage to be O(n), we need to pick b so that the 2<sup>b</sup> term isn't too big. That means that b will end up being approximately log n.

All of this is suggesting that we pick b = log n. However, *that choice won't work*. If we do this, then the O(2<sup>b</sup> · b · log b) term will work out to

> O(2<sup>b</sup> · b · log b)
>
> = O(2<sup>log n</sup> log n log log n)
>
> = O(n log n log log n).

(This works because 2<sup>log n</sup> = n, since log n is the inverse of 2<sup>n</sup>.) And now we're using more space usage than we started with.

However, what we *can* do is pick b = k log n for some constant k < 1 that we'll pick later. If we do this and apply properties of logarithms, we'll get the following:

> O(2<sup>b</sup> · b · log b)
>
> = O(2<sup>k log n</sup> · k log n · log (k log n))
>
> = O(2<sup>log n<sup>k</sup></sup> · k log n · (log k + log log n) *(properties of logarithms)*
>
> = O(2<sup>log n<sup>k</sup></sup> · log n · log log n) *(k is a constant)*
>
> = O(n<sup>k</sup> log n log log n)

Now, ***pick k = ½, meaning we pick b = ½ log n***. Then our space usage simplifies down to

> O(2<sup>b</sup> · b · log b)
>
> = O(n<sup>k</sup> log n log log n)
>
> = O(√n log n log log n)
>
> = O(n<sup>2/3</sup>).

Don't worry if you're scratching your head over that last step. The reason this works is that both log n and log log n grow slower than any root of n, and so we're able to conservatively bound the total space usage at O(n<sup>2/3</sup>).

Putting everything together, our space usage works out to

> O((n log n) / b + 2<sup>b</sup> · b · log b)
>
> = O((n log n) / ((1/2) log n) + n<sup>2/3</sup>)
>
> = O(n + n<sup>2/3</sup>)
>
> = **O(n)**.

(That last step follows because n<sup>2/3</sup> grows much more slowly than n does.) Amazing! We've managed to get linear space usage and constant query time!

The key insight here, that if the blocks are sufficiently small, we can precompute all of them and share space, is sometimes called the ***Method of Four Russians*** or a ***Four-Russians Speedup***. It takes its name from a paper by four Soviet computer scientists that first piloted the technique. I like to think of it as "divide, precompute, and conquer:" you break a large problem down into tiny pieces, precompute the solution to each tiny piece, and then combine solutions to the larger-scale problem and the smaller-scale problems together. It's an amazing technique that shows up all over advanced data structures as a way of removing a log factor from runtime or space usage.

So, we *must* be done at this point, right? Surely, there's no further room for improvement? Well, almost. But not quite.

It's great that we have O(n) total bits of storage, but exactly how many bits is that? If you work out the exact value, it's approximately 2n + n<sup>2/3</sup> bits. That is a *significant* improvement over where we started, but we are still using twice as many bits for our data structure as used by the original bitvector. And if that bitvector is enormous, that's can be a problem!

Our new goal will be to reduce our space usage *even further*. The goal will be to use *fewer than O(n) bits* for our data structure. That is, we're going to aim to get our space usage so low, we end up using fewer bits for our rank query structure than would be required by the original bit array itself.

How is this possible? Turns out we already have all the pieces we need. We just need to put them together in the right way.

### Step 6: Combine Strategies

We have essentially come up with two parallel strategies for computing ranks.

1. Subdivide the input into blocks of size log n. Write down prefix sums at the start of each block. Then recursively repeat this process on each block.
2. Split the input into blocks of size ½ log n. Write down prefix sums at the start of each block. Then precompute a table of how to handle queries within blocks of size ½ log n.

Strategy (1) gave us an O(n log* n)-bit data structure, with the space savings coming from the fact that it's more space-efficient to split things apart into blocks than it is to solve the problem directly. Strategy (2) gave us an O(n)-bit data structure, with the space savings coming from the fact that once we hit size ½ log n, we can precompute all possible queries.

Now for the last insight: what if we mix ideas (1) and (2) together? Specifically, here's how we're going to do things.

1. Split the input array of n bits into blocks of some block size b. Write down prefix sums at the start of each block.
2. Subdivide each block of size b into "miniblocks" of size ½ log n. Within each block, write down prefix sums at the start of each miniblock.
3. Build a Four Russians table that says, for each miniblock of size ½ log n and for each query index within such a block, what the prefix sum in that block at that index is.

Querying this data structure feels like a mix of the recursive and the Four Russians approach.

1. Find which block your query ends in. Write down the prefix sum at the start of that block.
2. Find which miniblock within that block your query ends in. Write down the prefix sum at the start of that miniblock.
3. Use the Four Russians table to look up the sum of the remaining bits within the miniblock.

Each step takes time O(1), so our queries still run in time O(1).

The intuition behind this approach is the following. The Four Russians table uses O(n<sup>2/3</sup>) space, which is already sublinear. To drop our space usage below n, we need to make sure our prefix sums don't use too many bits. By adding a middle layer, we can pick large-ish blocks so that the top-level prefix sums don't use too much space, but then avoid the cost of those larger blocks by using the Four Russians table.

If you work out the math on how much space this strategy will require, we will end up needing

- O((n log n) / b) bits for the top-level prefix sums,
- O((n log b) / log n) bits for the prefix sums within each miniblock (there are O(n / log n) miniblocks, and each miniblock index is b bits long), and
- O(n<sup>2/3</sup>) bits for the Four Russians table.

Adding this together, we get space usage O((n log n) / b + (n log b) / log n) + O(n<sup>2/3</sup>) bits. Once again, we find ourselves in a situation where if b is too small, we use too many bits at the top level, and if b is too big, we use too many bits one level below that. What choice of b gives the optimal balance?

Surprisingly, the optimal choice of b turns out to be **b = log<sup>2</sup> n** (that is, b = (log n)<sup>2</sup>). If you plug in this choice of b into the expression, we get the following space usage:

> O((n log n) / b + (n log b) / log n) + O(n<sup>2/3</sup>)
>
> = O((n log n) / log<sup>2</sup> n) + n log (log<sup>2</sup> n) / log n) + O(n<sup>2/3</sup>)
>
> = O(n / log n + n log log n / log n) + O(n<sup>2/3</sup>)
>
> = **O(n · (log log n / log n))**

That is a weird-looking space usage - is it good? Is it bad? What does it mean? Well, notice that even though log n grows slowly, log log n grows even more slowly than that. As an example, if n ≈ 4,000,000,000, then log n ≈ 32 and log log n ≈ 5. That means that log log n / log n ≈ 1/7. So the total number of bits we need for our data structure, O(n · (log log n / log n)), is a ***sublinear*** number of bits! In other words, ***we use fewer bits for our data structure than the original array of bits needs!***

That isn't to say that we can throw the original array of bits away. Our data structure requires us to still have access to it, since once you're down to a miniblock you need to use the bits of that miniblock as an index into the Four Russians table. Rather, if you already have the n bits of the original bit array lying around, you can add in a *sublinear* number of additional bits and suddenly be able to compute ranks in time O(1).

So SURELY we are done at this point, right? We MUST have gone as far as we can go, *right*? Well...

### Step 7: The Story Continues

From a Theoryland perspective, we could call it quits here. We have proved that it's possible to compute ranks in a bitvector that's n bits long using fewer than n additional bits.

This combined approach is an example of a ***succinct data structure***. Intuitively, a succinct data structure is one whose space usage equals the space needed to write out the data, plus something that grows more slowly than that. If you're familiar with [little-o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation), a succinct data structure is one whose space usage is X + o(X), where X is the number of bits needed to write out the data itself.

But in other senses, in Theoryland, we aren't yet done. We know that it's possible to solve ranking in constant time and with space O(n · (log log n / log n)). Is that the best possible space we can achieve with constant query time, or can we go lower? Turns out we can do much better than this. The approach I've shown here was invented in 1989 by Guy Jacobson in a frequently-cited PhD thesis. Recently (2019), Huacheng Yu published a paper [describing a set of theoretical optimal succinct rank data structures](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3313276.3316352) that have the best possible tradeoffs between query time and space usage.

Then there's what things look like in practice. The structure we discussed here doesn't perform super well in practice due to the high constant factors required for reading variable-bit numbers (see the above C code, for example) and because of the poor locality of reference of the multiple table lookups. As an example, the [poppy](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Edga/papers/zhou-sea2013.pdf) data structure supports fast ranking in practice with minimal overhead.

Finally, there are generalizations and other related problems. The [wavelet tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet_Tree) generalizes rank on bitvectors to rank on arbitrary strings. In the generalized version of this operation, the rank operation takes as input an index and a character, then asks "how many times does this character appear before this index?" This has applications in compressed data structures for text, like the FM-index. The inverse of the rank operation is called ***select***, where queries are of the form "where is the ith 1 bit in this bitvector?" Using similar techniques to succinct rank, plus some extra problem-specific insights, it's possible to get select queries that take time O(1) with sublinear overhead.

Hope this helps!

(This post is based on [a lecture I gave in my data structures course](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs166/cs166.1226/lectures/14/Slides14.pdf) on succinct rank and select.)